# How do I split a string not separated by commas into an array of objects with properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a string of questions and answers which looks like this:

```
var string = "(1) blah blah blah ANSWER: bling (2) bleh bleh bleh ANSWER: bleng"
```

and I want to turn it into an array of objects such:

```
var array = [
  {
    question: "(1) blah blah blah", 
    answer: "ANSWER: bling"
  },
  {
    question: "(2) bleh bleh bleh", 
    answer: "ANSWER: bleng"
  },
]
```

The issue is that where I want to split each object is at (1), (2), (3), and such.

I've tried `var array = string.split("(")` to attempt to split the objects at the first parenthesis of each question number, but "(" is not a valid split point.

Is there any way I can split at those points with the .split method? And once the split is successful, how do I assign the properties question: and answer:?

Comment: split the string using your identifier ANSWER:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match a `(` followed by non-`(` characters, then map each submatch to an object by splitting on the space before `ANSWER`:

```js
const string = "(1) blah blah blah ANSWER: bling (2) bleh bleh bleh ANSWER: bleng";
const arr = string
  .match(/\([^(]+\S/g)
  .map((substr) => {
    const [question, answer] = substr.split(/ (?=ANSWER)/);
    return { question, answer };
  });
console.log(arr);
```

`\([^(]+\S`:

- `\(` - Literal `(`
- `[^(]+` - One or more non-`(` characters
- `\S` - Non-space character (this ensures that a trailing space after the last word in an ANSWER isn't matched)

Comment: How do I access the properties of this `arr`? Like if I wanted to display the HTML of a paragraph element as the question property of the first object?

Comment: The same way you'd access properties of any array of objects. `arr[0].question`

Comment: Got it. Thanks! Using a regex is a smart way to go about this. Could you explain what's going on in the `.map` method? the split of each substring object into the properties? I don't fully understand .map–I suppose I should read up on the Mozilla page.

Comment: `.map` transforms one array into another based on the return value of the callback. Here, the array of strings gets transformed into an array of objects because the callback returns an object.

Comment: Ah I see now: `.match` turns the string into an array of strings `arr`, split at the defined regex. Then the `.map` method creates a new array from the parent array `arr` by splitting each string in `arr` into an object with question and answer properties. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve this with regex, that would match everything from start `(1)` to end (beginning of next parenthesis). This regex will match question in group 1 and answer in group 2:

```js
const regex = /(\(\d+?\).*?)(ANSWER: .+?)(?:\()/g
```

Also check out string.match method, you'll need this to get array of all matches: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match